# Expected value of the reciprocal

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables, expectation

Suppose $X_n>0$ is a sequence of positive random variables such that

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[X_n\right]\longrightarrow \infty\quad(1)
$$

Given this, I am wondering whether there exist conditions to guarantee that

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{X_n}\right]\longrightarrow 0.
$$

or is it an immediate consequence of $(1)$?

Comment: Not an immediate consequence! Consider the case where $X_n$ takes values $1$ and $n$ with equal probability $1/2$.

Comment: I think the condition $(\forall k \in \mathbb{R}_+) \lim_{n \to \infty} P(X_n < k) = 0$ is sufficient, though I don't know whether it's necessary.

Comment: Ah, no, it's not sufficient. Counterexample: $X_n$ takes the value $2^{-n}$ with probability $2^{-n}$, and $2^n$ otherwise.

Comment: @ConnorHarris could you please check my condition below?

Comment: Your condition (if I'm interpreting correctly) is that there's some fixed $C$ for which $P(1/X_n \leq C) = 1$ holds for all $n$. In this case, my first counterexample (tossing a coin with sides marked $1$ and $n$) still works.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_n$ be a positive random variable with: $$\mathsf P(X_n=n)=\frac12=\mathsf P(X_n=\frac1n)$$

Then $X_n$ and $X_n^{-1}$ have the same distribution.

This with: $$\mathsf EX_n^{-1}=\mathsf EX_n=\frac12n+\frac12\frac1n\to\infty$$

I have no direct answer on your request for sufficient conditions.

Comment: After some computations I think that having $1/X_n\leq C$ is sufficient. In fact 
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{X_n}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{X_n}\mathbb{I}_{\{X_n\leq M \} }\right]+\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{X_n}\mathbb{I}_{\{X_n\geq M \} }\right]$$

whence

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{X_n}\right]\leq C\,\mathbb{P}\left[X_n\leq M\right]+\frac{1}{M}\,\mathbb{P}\left[ X_n\geq M  \right]$$

Comment: @AlmostSureUser And what guarantees that the RHS of your last inequality converges to zero?

Comment: ok, you are totally right, it is not enough, I need to think more.